# Does it make sense to use Lasso regression for recommendation systems?

Tags: regression, lasso, recommender-system

I'm really intrigued by Lasso Regression, and it seems like a potential candidate for estimating “objective” ratings for items based on the users who watched them. The user data is sparse, and the estimation of the overall rating can be a regression problem.

To be clear: I would be using this for a Netflix-prize type algorithm where the average rating would be replaced by a “true” rating based on this method.

Is there any problem with this? Are there other things that Lasso regression tends to be used for that could serve as examples?

Comment: Can you give some more details of your approach? For example, what do you mean by 'overall rating'? What variable are you trying to predict, and what are your independent variables?